# Polygon of Voronoi cell using scipy.spatial?

Tags: python, polygon, polygonize, voronoi-thiessen, scipy.spatial

I have points (e.g., lat, lon pairs of cell tower locations) and I need to get the polygon of the Voronoi cells they form.

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

tower = [[ 24.686 ,  46.7081],
       [ 24.686 ,  46.7081],
       [ 24.686 ,  46.7081]]

c = Voronoi(towers)
```

Now, I need to get the polygon boundaries in lat,lon coordinates for each cell (and what was the centroid this polygon surrounds). I need this Voronoi to be bounded as well. Meaning that the boundaries don't go to infinity, but rather within a bounding box.

Comment: place some dummy points around the far-extremity to bound the cells then clip the result to a box. As to getting the coordinates of the polygons you will need to break them down into points from parts.. do you have access to other libraries like OGR or QGIS? What kind of object is c, is it a shapefile?

Comment: c is a scipy.spatial.qhull.Voronoi object. I am not experienced with GIS .. would this be easy if I install QGIS?

Comment: QGIS has its own voronoi generator, from shapefile points: http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/voronoipolygons.html which creates a shapefile output that can be clipped with QGIS (or OGR) and then broken down to strings of points with QGSFeature/QGSGeometry objects. see http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html

Comment: [From Voronoi tessellation to Shapely polygons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548363/from-voronoi-tessellation-to-shapely-polygons) gives you a solution